# How to do many simultaneous jsoup sessions (Spring boot project and concurrancy)

Tags: java, spring, performance, concurrency, spring-boot

Maybe this is a very basic Java question. Forgive me if it is.

I have this Spring Boot project that needs to, for every registered user, automatically (in the background) connect periodically to a website and download many documents and/or check for changes.

The "download/check" system was externally developed. Every method was static.

Am I right thinking that it IS a problem when I want to have more than one simultaneous execution?
Even if it has all specific connection parameters through parameters?

Thinking of that, I removed the static annotation on almost every method. Now I need to create a new instance for every execution.

When I began adding it to my Spring boot project, I realized there are a bunch of services that make simultaneous connections to a web service, and there I didn't even care about concurrency.

AFAIK, each service is a singleton. Right? So there is no new instance for every connection. Right?

My question is: If I happen to have 100's of users... How should I integrate the jsoup code?

1. Should I create a new instance from a service?
2. Should I convert it to a Service itself and just @Autowire it to the service where the process is triggered?
3. Is it better to make it static? (this one I don't think so, but maybe I'm wrong)
4. Any other option?

If possible, please add a reason why I should follow your suggestion.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd say if your classes are not maintaining any state then it is actually a good thing if everything is static cause this gets you rather close to functional programming. If you are then passing everything as an parameter to a method and don't have any state in the class (not the method) then everything is kept on the stack which is not shared amongst threads. Long story short: thread-safe.

If you maintain any type of state in your classes – be it services or components – then you have to make sure that they are executing in a thread safe way. One of the easiest ways is to change the `@Scope` of that particular bean to prototype or for instance request as you are running this as a web app.

Comment: When the main static method (1) gets called, it creates a Map<String, String> and call some other static methods (2, 3, etc) passing that map as parameter. Those methods (2, 3, etc) return some other object, not that map. Sometimes that map gets updated inside method number 2 and those changes are used later on inside method 3, for example. Is it still safe to use it if executed more than once simultaneously? Did I made myself clear?

Comment: In this case you are changing states of the class itself. Therefore you should take care of isolating the calls. Either by making everything which is static non-static and using a prototype Scope or by synchronizing the calls to make it thread safe.

Comment: Just to be sure: Need to use prototype Scope or synchronize even if the map is created in the body of method 1?

Comment: As I understood in your last comment method 2 is changing the map, then yes.